# DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

i have a constraint problem with a foreign key. I have two object (User and UserSession) with a manyToOne relationship: an user can have many UserSession. I tried to insert a new UserSession but i got an DataIntegrityViolationException.

Here is my usersession class:

```
public class UserSession implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    private String userSessionUUId;

    other parameters ....
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userUUId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
```

my User class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements Serializable {

    some parameters

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = UserSession.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserSession> userSessions = new LinkedList<>();
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void addUserSession(@RequestBody @Valid UserSession userSession) {
    object.createEntity(userSession);
}
```

i posted this request:

```
curl -i -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{othersparameters, "userUUId": "EEEEEE"}' http://localhost:8080/path
```

The error:

```
[dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'useruuid' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Can someone helps me?

Cheers

Comment: Can you paste controller code?

Comment: What is that you don't understand about this error? `Column 'useruuid' cannot be null`

Comment: yes. useruuid is the foreign key. I debug the request and i think, i have the send an user and not the useruuid

Comment: Does your User entity have I'd field and is it batabase generated?